# Delete a table row on button click in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, delete-row

I have a table with the following 3 columns where each row is dynamically appended.

- Condition : Is a mere WHERE clause conditional statement string
- Remove : A button that removes that row (Removes a condition)
- Join with : A drop down combo

When the user clicks on the <kbd>Remove</kbd> button, that particular row needs to be removed.

I have written the code for this, but nothing happens and am not getting any errors on the console as well.

[image: form]

**Code in Context**

```
$("#whereConditionTable").append(
        "<tr>"+
            "<td>"+conditionString+"</td>"+
            "<td><button id='removeConditionBtn' name='removeConditionBtn' class='btn btn-default'><img src='resources/images/removeWhereCondition.png' width='25px' height='25px'></button>"+
            "<td>"+
                "<select id='where-Condition-Join-Combo' name='where-Condition-Join-Combo' class='form-control'>"+
                  "<option value='1'>Join using</option>"+
                  "<option value='2'>AND</option>"+
                  "<option value='3'>OR</option>"+
                "</select>"+
              "</td>"+
        "</tr>"
   );

    document.getElementById("removeConditionBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
    removeWhereCondition();
}, false);
```

**removeWhereCondition()**

```
function removeWhereCondition()
{
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
}
```

Any suggestions in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things to fix:

1. You're combining jQuery and vanilla JavaScript (`getElementById`), so I've tidied some of that up and rewritten it as jQuery.
2. HTML documents can not have repeating `ID`s. If your `append` ran more than once, it would create additional `#removeConditionBtn` and `#where-Condition-Join-Combo` elements, and JS would cease to work. I've changed these to classes, which are reusable.
3. Your `addEventListener` to bind a `click` event was only going to bind to (one) `#removeConditionBtn` element that existed when the code was first run. If the table contents changed to include additional buttons, your binding wouldn't have updated (even if you were using class rather than ID). I've rewritten this using jQuery `on` on the table itself, so the `click` event will still fire even as the contents of the table change.

Working demonstration below:

```js
var conditionString = "text";

$("#whereConditionTable").append(
  "<tr>" +
  "<td>" + conditionString + "</td>" +
  "<td><button class='removeConditionBtn' name='removeConditionBtn' class='btn btn-default'><img src='resources/images/removeWhereCondition.png' alt='Remove' width='25px' height='25px'></button>" +
  "<td>" +
  "<select class='where-Condition-Join-Combo' name='where-Condition-Join-Combo' class='form-control'>" +
  "<option value='1'>Join using</option>" +
  "<option value='2'>AND</option>" +
  "<option value='3'>OR</option>" +
  "</select>" +
  "</td>" +
  "</tr>"
);

$("#whereConditionTable").on("click", ".removeConditionBtn", function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="whereConditionTable"></table>
```

Comment: Thanks. This actually helped.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function deleteRow(r) {
    var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(i);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table id="myTable">

<tr>
  <td>Row 1</td>
  <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Row 2</td>
  <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Row 3</td>
  <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are using jQuery. You could try:

```
$('#removeConditionButton').on('click', function(element) {
    $(element).closest('tr').remove();
})
```

By the way, it seem you are using id-property incorrectly. Id's should be unique and each page can have only one element with same id. In this case, you should use class instead of id.